# Savingg a String using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, string, sharedpreferences

I have some code that collects a number, I am able to prove that I am genuating a number will im doing this but when I go to save the number using this code

```
public void SaveScore()
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("Score", (StringScore));
    }
```

Then I call it back later in another page with this code

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
ScoreString = (settings.getString("Score", "0"));
Score.setText(ScoreString + "%");
```

It comes up as 0 I know that it is the default number so why am I not saving the number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've forgotten to do an `editor.commit()` to commit your changes.